# Unable to Select the date in a date picker which is having two month blocks-- http://www.cleartrip.com/flights

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Unable to pick a date from the website [][1]http://www.cleartrip.com/flights
Below is the code that i have tried. Please help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

Error while running the code:   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with tag name == table (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

```html
//Select a date from the date picker-- Simple(Select July 18 2015)
  driver.findElement(By.id("DepartDate")).click();
  
  //Wait for some time
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  
  //table div
  WebElement tableWholeBlock = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));
  List<WebElement> tableWholeBlockVals = tableWholeBlock.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
  
   
  WebElement lastBlockTable = tableWholeBlockVals.get(1);
  
  
  //WebElement lastMonthblk = tableWholeBlock.findElement(By.className("monthBlock last")); 
  
  //WebElement lastMonthblk = driver.findElement(By.className("monthBlock last"));
  
  
  
  WebElement monthTable = lastBlockTable.findElement(By.tagName("table"));
  
  List<WebElement> tableRow = monthTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  List<WebElement> tableCells = monthTable.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
  
  for (WebElement cells : tableCells) {
   if(cells.getText().equals("18")){
    cells.click();
   }
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the looping and go straight to selecting a date if you use the correct XPath expression.

Example XPath to select the 18th day of the second month on display:

```
WebElement myDay = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'monthBlock') and contains(@class, 'last')]/table[@class='calendar']//td[normalize-space()='18']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Date Picker,it will display dialog which has two months i.e., current month and next month. You can use below xpath to select 29th date(today's date) of current month.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a"));
```